# Facing wierd CSS Issue just on native IOs (iphone)

Tags: css, ios, lottie, after-effects, inline-styles

Hope someone can help me with this:
Only on native devices my icons (DOT-lottie-files) are cut off on all edges.
Looks like this:
[Native iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W39JF.png)

However, if I display my site on iPhone or any other IOs device in the chrome-developer-tools, then it looks as it suposed to be. Same on any Android I have.
Here you can see one example:
[iPhone with dev-tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkep2.png)

So I assume I have to change something on my CSS?
At the moment I placed this line of CSS to get the Icons centered:

```
style="width: 120px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
```

Maybe I need to mention that there is some bootstrap too.
The whole block looks like this:
[How I placed the inline CSS:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Taaqf.png)

But I feel like there must be just some other CSS to adress the problem.
So can someone please have a look on this? This drives me crazy!

This is the site: https://monzy.app/

I've been able to reproduce the issue on two iPhones and one iPad (all native). On Android and in the Developer tools it looks normal. I tried to change the width in CSS and added some padding as well but didnt get what I need.

Kind Regards and thank you for any help!

Comment: FYI Chrome dev tools only changes screen size and user agent. It's still running the Blink engine.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. "Weird issue" isn't useful to the community.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out meanwhile. It's not an issue with CSS, it's just because Lottie features (created by After Effects) are limited on iOS. As I removed the Gaussian blur, the problem disappeared too. So if someone faces similar issues, it might be related to missing features. Here, you can check the Lottie Features for all devices: [Link to Lottie Supported Features](https://lottiefiles.com/supported-features)

[Icon one is without the blur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVReu.png)